# SQL datawarehousing extend dimension with extra info

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssas-2012

I have a dimension core.DimAd which contains ad information. i.e.

```
PK AdKey  AdvertiserID  CampaignID 
1         Ad company 1  Campaign 1
2         Ad company 2  Campaign 2
3         Ad company 4  Campaign 3
```

I then want to create a new extension table like AdChannelExtension

```
PK ChannelExtensionKey  Adkey  Channel
   1                    1      Sales
   2                    1      Production
   3                    2      Sales
```

I then want to create a view

VWDimAd

which joins the two tables on ad key and use as a dimension in SSAS.  When it combinees the rows however it's non unique and won't process due to duplicate keys.  How do you deal with this scenario? I cannot alter the original table. Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just create a composite key of `PK AdKey` and `PK Channel ExtensionKey`?

Comment: That's most likely a *different* dimension, unless you never intend to have a campaign across channels

Comment: Isn't this just a many-to-many dimension? I would google that and do some further reading rather than shoving Channels into the Ad dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite key in your view and use that in SSAS:

```
select cast(a.AdKey as nvarchar(20))
         + '-'
         + cast(e.ChannelExtensionKey as nvarchar(20)) as AdAdChannelCompKey
      ,a.AdvertiserID
      ,a.CampaignID
      ,e.Channel
from DimAd a
    inner join DimAdChannelExtension e
        on(a.AdKey = e.AdKey)
```